# Alpakka JMS Transaction

Tags: scala, jms, akka-stream, oracle-aq, alpakka

I'm playing with `Alpakka` and its `JMS` connector to dequeue data from `Oracle AQ`. I could come up with the very basic implementation below by following **[this](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/jms.html)** guide.

My question is how I can make it transactional, so that I can guarantee that my message won't be lost if an exception is thrown.

```
object ConsumerApp extends App {
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("actor-system")
    implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val connectionFactory = AQjmsFactory.getConnectionFactory(getOracleDataSource())

    val out = JmsSource.textSource(
        JmsSourceSettings(connectionFactory).withQueue("My_Queue")
    )

    val sink = Sink.foreach { message: String =>
        println("in sink: " + message)
        throw new Exception("") // !!! MESSAGE IS LOST !!!
    }

    out.runWith(sink, materializer)
}
```

If it was `PL/SQL`, the solution would be like this:

```
DECLARE
  dequeue_options            DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
  message_properties         DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
  message_handle             RAW (44);
  msg                        SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE;
BEGIN
  DBMS_AQ.dequeue (
      queue_name           => 'My_Queue',
      dequeue_options      => dequeue_options,
      message_properties   => message_properties,
      payload              => msg,
      msgid                => message_handle
  );

  -- do something with the message

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior when a stream stage fails is to shut down the entire stream. You'll have to decide how you want to [handle errors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-error.html) in the stream. One approach, for example, is to [restart](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-error.html#delayed-restarts-with-a-backoff-stage) the stream with a backoff strategy.

Also, since you're using the Alpakka JMS connector, set the [acknowledgement mode](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v0.15/jms/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/jms/Jms.scala#L15) to `ClientAcknowledge` (this is available since Alpakka 0.15). With this configuration, messages that aren't acknowledged can be delivered again through the JMS source. For example:

```
val jmsSource: Source[Message, NotUsed] = JmsSource(
  JmsSourceSettings(connectionFactory)
    .withQueue("My_Queue")
    .withAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.ClientAcknowledge)
)

val result = jmsSource
  .map {
    case textMessage: TextMessage =>
      val text = textMessage.getText
      textMessage.acknowledge()
      text
  }
  .runForeach(println)
```

Comment: So, it is a new feature which was released only several hours before I asked the question. I am so lucky then :).

Comment: I'll try it as soon as possible

Comment: What is the best way to try it now? It's not in any public repository yet.